# Why does my 3G key blocks my eth0 interface and how to solve this?

Tags: debian, networking

I have a linux PC (Debian Squeeze) which is located into a room in another town (I cannot physically access to this PC from where I am)

This PC is linked to internet using an internet box. I can connect to this PC using ssh through port 22 (actually I have a NAT from remote box port XXXX to PC's port 22).

One of my collegue connects a 3G key. I then use [sakis script](http://www.sakis3g.org/) to connect this PC to 3G network, and then my ssh connection is hanged (Broken pipe). My collegue can still access to the PC from his local network using ssh; I can't.

What are the reasons why 3G connection stops the external ssh connection ?
How can I solve this issue (keeping my ssh connection opened while 3G connection is made) ?

**Edit: additional information**

I connect using the NAT, before 3G script is launched

IP does not change for eth0 (the interface I use to connect)

A new interface is added after 3G connection :`ppp0 Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol`

ip route (before 3G connection)

```
172.16.210.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.210.254 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.50 
default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0
```

ip route (after 3G connection)

```
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.99.122.183 
172.16.210.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.210.254 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.50 
default via 10.64.64.64 dev ppp0
```

Comment: To clarify: a) your colleague is connecting via the local network whereas you're trying to connect via the NAT? b) Did the IP address on eth0 or the routing table ("ip route" output) change? c) Not familiar with the script, did it add another interface (like a virtual one) to the system?

Comment: **$a)** I try to connect using the NAT, before 3G script is launched | **b)** the ip did not change for eth0 (the interface I use) **c)** yes, it added an interface: `ppp0 Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol`

Comment: Did the output of the routing table change when it added the ppp0 interface? It may be routing the response out an interface we're not expecting.

Comment: You can check the routing table with the "ip route" command BTW

Comment: I added this information in the edited question

Comment: OK so the routing table is changing, that might be the problem then, what IP address are you connecting from so I can see which routing rule it's matching your session against.

Comment: I connect from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.50

Comment: I thought you said that you were connecting through port forwarding on the router? 192.168 is a private IP range, so you might have a different source IP than you're expecting. If you're coming in through the internet my thinking is that you're ssh'ing through the router which connects via eth0's normal IP address and when the 3G client changes the default route from "192.168.0.254 via eth0" to "10.64.64.64 via ppp0" it starts routing the packets out the ppp0 interface with that ip address. When the 3G isn't on check how you're showing up to the system with a "who -m" after ssh'ing in.

Comment: Ho, yes, sorry. Here is the result of who -m:

`root     pts/0        2013-04-11 00:24 (31.36.141.175)`

Comment: Alright, yeah with that IP and that routing table the issue's definitely a routing one, you're coming in eth0 and you're going out ppp0 (with ppp0's IP, which your client isn't going to correspond with a valid connection ,since it sees the connection as with the other public IP and ignores the packets). How you want to fix that kind of depends on the details of our setup. It might make sense to write a script to reset the default gateway to the pre-ppp0 value and to just give ppp0 anything in the 10.0.0.0/8 network

Comment: I don't know how to write that script. Do you have some reference documentation ? And I would like to make eth0 the default route until it is unplugged (and then make ppp0 the default route). Is it possible ?

Comment: You can do it with the "ip route" command. For more information "ip help route" should give you some usage and the manpage touches on routing a bit as well. [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/) touches on basic usage. Basically you'd need three rules: 1) add the rule to forward 10.0.0.0/8 t ppp0 2) delete current default gateway 3) add new default gateway. All three of which are described in the link.

Comment: For the interactivity thing, no that functionality hasn't been built yet, to my knowledge. The work you'd have to do is probably more than you'd want to. You should be able to work this into your normal workflow for setting up the 3G connection as part of a script invocation.

Answer (score 1):

After running that script, your default route points to another interface. Your ssh connection's data get sent there, but get thrown away because they have the wrong address, are NATted by the 3G network to some unrelated address, and/or whatever.

Solution: Add an explicit route. The variable $SSH_CLIENT tells you where the connection is coming from.

```
# set $SSH_CLIENT
# ip route replace $1 via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused with your script. Should I add this to the 3G connection script ? After or before 3G connection command ? Or elsewhere ?
It is $1 I should use but where is it set ?

Comment: You can add it to the beginning of your 3G connection script, sure.  The `$1` is set by the `set $SSH_CLIENT` line, see the shell's manual page.

Comment: NB: I fixed the `route` command, should have been `ip route`.